# how to iterate and retrive just the values from a json object with ruby

Tags: json, ruby, loops, object

Say I have a simple json object like

```
{"a" :"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"}
```

In ruby, how can I iterate through that object just so I can get the values 1 2 and 3.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have the object as a string.

```
require 'json'
json_obj = '{"a" :"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"}'
values = JSON.parse(json_obj).values
```

will provide you with the array

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

JSON.parse ,  parses the json string into a ruby object, in this case an instance of a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html).  The [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html) class has a method [values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) which returns an array containing the values or each hash entry.